# Textmate go to the function definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

Lets say I have this in my controller

`@appointment.add_appointer`

Is there a shortcut in Textmate to jump to the `add_appointer` function definition in my appointment.rb model?

Comment: it's supposed to be `^ f` but it's not that efficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, unfortunately. I think the fastest way is to probably use:

```
Command+T <type appointment.rb>
```

Now in open file

```
Command+Shift+T <type method name>
```

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of TextMate is that it can be simply extended to fulfil you needs!
I've written a TextMate Bundle command (you can easily assign it to **Ctrl+]** for example) that lookup for the definition of the class or method under the caret and displays it in a tooltip, along with the file name and the line where it was find.

Check it out: **[Add a shortcut to TextMate to lookup a class or method definition in a tooltip](http://claudiofloreani.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-shortcut-to-textmate-to-lookup.html)**

Comment: that's great, I am using it now. Is there any way for it to go to the file and line, where it found the method/class definition?

Comment: That's a good idea. Textmate already has a Jump to method definition in the Ruby on Rails bundle (just press 'CTRL+F'). However it is obsolete code and often I find this a little too intrusive, sometimes I just want to take a look at the parameters or recall where the method or class was defined. So I  have rewritten the code (check the previous link) to copy the matching file to the clipboard, so if you want only to have a glance at the definition in tooltip just press CTRL+], and when you want to jump to that file you can then press CTRL+L and CTRL+V. You can even jump to the line with CMD+L

Comment: @ClaudioFloreani Extremely helpful utility.  I think you mean CMD+T and CMD+V to jump to a different file (as it states in your post), followed by CMD+L in either case.